# Parse new line character from input field string

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to print two lines of text inside DIV, when the string form input filed contain '\n' character.

HTML:

```
<div id="renderdiv">Some text</div>
<br><br>
<label for="take">Enter text: </label>
<input type="text" name="enter" id="take">
```

Javascript:

```
var data = {"jsontext":"First line\nSecond line"};
var textToAdd = data.jsontext;

var getInput = document.getElementById('take');
var divPrint = document.getElementById('renderdiv');

divPrint.innerText = textToAdd;

getInput.addEventListener('change', function() {
    var nonParsed = this.value;
    divPrint.innerText = nonParsed;
});
```

If you add in input filed **"Test1\nTest2"**, I wish to be injected in DIV and printed in two lines. I try:

```
var nonParsed = this.value.replace('\n', '<br>')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
var nonParsed = '<p>' + this.value.split('\n').join('</p><p>') + '</p>'  
divPrint.innerHTML = nonParsed;
```